# How to fetch data from a column and display that data using 2 columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, pivot

Here is the example table:

[image: Input_table]

And I want output like this:

[image: Output]

Comment: Hi. Please provide the information in the question and not as images that are not displayed.

Comment: Sorry that the images were not displaying i'm posting for the first time but you got the point which asking right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select wf_name,
    count(*) filter(where crt_by = 'ADHOC') adhoc,
    count(*) filter(where crt_by = 'SCHEDULE') schedule
from mytable
group by wf_name
```